# Enumerate not to reset counter (resuming enumerate counter)

Tags: enumerate, counters

I have two enumerates

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 5 + 7 = 12
\item 9 + 1 = 10
\end{enumerate}

lorel ipsum, blah blah blah

\begin{enumerate}
\item 5 * 7 = 12
\item A+B = C
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

How can I make the item numbering goes like, 1,2,3,4 instead of 1,2,1,2? I know I can do by adding to second enumerate block

```
\setcounter{enumi}{3}
```

but this can cause problems if i change first enumerate block later?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [`enumitem`][http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem] package?

Comment: Load the `enumitem` package, and use `\begin{enumerate}[series=foo]` for your first `enumerate` environment, and `\begin{enumerate}[resume=foo]` for the second. Of course, the choice of name for the `series` is your own.

Answer (score 4):

Upon Mario's suggestion I found out that solution is really simple, just put [resume] after the enumerate like

```
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item 5 + 7 = 12
\item 9 + 1 = 10
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: This doesn't work without `enumitem`!

Comment: Also if you change the format of the number using `label=`, then remember to use `resume*` otherwise the format from the preceeding list is not continued.